# multipart/form-data combined with JSON post fields

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I'm trying to send a `multipart/form-data` form to a REST API. It should be possible to send files, but the other POST fields should be delivered as `JSON`.

That's how it should look like:

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=entity
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "vacancyId": "xxx",
    "locationId": xxx,
    "salutationId": xxx,
    "firstname": "xxx",
    "lastname": "xxx",
    "xingProfile": "xxx",
    "mobileNumber": "xxx",
    "emailAddress": "xxx",
    "comment": "xxx",
    "mediaOptionId": xxx
}
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Archive.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
<@INCLUDE *xxx\Archive.zip*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="CV.pdf"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<@INCLUDE *xxx\CV.pdf*
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

I'm trying to solve this with PHP `curl`.

This is the current code for it:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: ' . $contentType));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// ...

$data = json_decode($data, true); // data comes as JSON string

$tmpData = $data;
$tmpData['file'] = null; // remove files
$tmpData = (object) array_filter((array) $tmpData); // filter empty values
$json = json_encode($tmpData); // generate JSON entity

// generate data for posting
$postData = array();
$postData['entity'] = 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' . $json;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'));

// go through uploaded files
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['file']); $i++) {
    $file = $data['file'][$i];
    $uploadedFile = curl_file_create($file['tmp_name'], $file['type'], $file['name']);

    $postData['file'] = $uploadedFile;
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

The request looks ok for me, but for some reason the API is not able to parse the JSON. I'm pretty sure it's because of `Content-Type: application/json`, which doesn't work like this. But maybe it's another problem. Any ideas?

This is the request, which the API gets:

```
: --------------------------259e507e48ab52a4

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity"



Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{"vacancyId":xxx,"locationId":xxx,"salutationId":xxx,"firstname":"xxx","lastname":"xxx","emailAddress":"xxx","mobileNumber":"xxxx","comment":"xxx","mediaOptionId":xxxx,"xingProfile":"xxx"}

--------------------------259e507e48ab52a4--
```

PS: Files can be ignored for now. It seems to be a problem with the JSON part.

Comment: I noticed that in the line `'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'` you are using single quotes. Try with double quotes.

Comment: @pumbo Unfortunately same problem

Comment: FYI: I removed `'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'` completely and now it works.