# Cannot parse a `Content-Disposition: form-data` payload using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I've already read many posts about this topic but it looks like that none of them relate to my context.

I have a JS library which sends to the backend a **POST** request containing data formatted this way:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryDjoP6y6CoTH58A26
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

[{ <JSON formatted data> }}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryDjoP6y6CoTH58A26--
```

I know because I've used the browser inspector. My problem is that I cannot make to get this data. The conventional `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns an empty string. Trying to investigate further with `apache_request_headers()` thist is what the backend reveives:

```
Array
(
    [Cookie] => PHPSESSID=e8tlf5aocqmb5eu2qliu7pnkl4; arpadmin=s1pg7pg31kl2e9sj96kg2arqc4; __gsas=ID=6ed6b402c3253656:T=1702304073:RT=1702304073:S=ALNI_Mbb4fbtcgyhQiVS58b1D5bl7hnPmA
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Referer] => http://myhostname.mydomain.org/arp/lat.php?mese=1&anno=2024
    [Origin] => http://myhostname.mydomain.org
    [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEAp4qyLXkJs3nO4a
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.0.0
    [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
    [Dnt] => 1
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [Pragma] => no-cache
    [Accept] => application/json
    [Content-Length] => 368
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Host] => myhostname.mydomain.org
)
```

Where are my data?

Comment: Have you tried looking in $_POST?

Comment: have you enabled https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading

Comment: @ADyson yes, it's empty.

Comment: Hm. Can you show the code and data which generates this request in this format? Sending a multipart request which then contains JSON within it is a bit odd.

Comment: Check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains.

Comment: @ADyson good question: I'm using a library that lets you to have a spreadsheet into a webpage. here (https://bossanova.uk/jspreadsheet/v4/cases/data-persistence) what I'm trying to do, and here (https://github.com/jspreadsheet/ce) the GH project page.

Comment: As per the information you shared, your JSON string should be available at `$_POST['data']` and applying `json_decode()` on that should get the expected data... unless the request is something else like PATCH or PUT.

Comment: @CBroe `[REQUEST_METHOD] => POST`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you're right, if you promote your comment to answer I can mark it as the solution, thanks.

Comment: @DanieleI found the source code it uses: https://github.com/jspreadsheet/ce/blob/master/src/index.js#L1109  . Yuk...who puts JSON inside form data...that's a very strange thing to do. While it's mucky, it ought not to cause issues, but it depends a bit on how the library which actually sends the request would then format the data. I found that too: https://github.com/jsuites/jsuites/blob/master/src/plugins/ajax.js

Comment: Anyway it sounds like the data was in $_POST after all, although  earlier you told me that was empty

Comment: @ADyson because I'm sure it was. The library documentation is very stingy, so the first thing I did was checking the type of REQUEST_METHOD sent, and I remember my disappointment when I tried to dump the $_POST without getting anything. Obviously I did some very silly mistake.

Comment: Topically related: [multipart/form-data combined with JSON post fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35431303/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to submit JSON to an API end-point is to use `Content-Type: application/json`, which requires reading raw data from `php://input` and parsing it yourself. But your JavaScript library is not using that. It's using one of the two classical formats supported by HTML forms, which PHP will automagically decode into `$_POST`:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `multipart/form-data` <-- This is yours

Your raw JSON will be available at `$_POST['data']` and applying [json_decode()](https://php.net/json_decode) on that should get the expected data... unless the request is something else like PATCH or PUT (inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` if unsure).